# Rails 3 why filter_parameters doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this line `config.filter_parameters += [:password, :efile, :title]` in application.rb.
But when I try to save a model like this:

```
 @claim_db[:xml] = xml_builder.to_xml.gsub('utf-8', 'utf-16')
 @claim_db[:title] = title.present? ? title : nil
 @claim_db[:applicants] = applicants.present? ? applicants : nil
 @claim_db[:native_number] = nn.present? ? nn : nil
 @claim_db[:change_date] = Time.now
 @claim_db[:is_signed] = false
 @claim_db[:with_errors] = errors.count > 0
 @claim_db.save!
```

in a log a get:

```
  ←[1m←[36mAREL (2.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mINSERT INTO [edocs] ([eclaim_id], [materialtitl
e_id], [is_secondary], [title], [ext], [size], [code], [receive_date], [reg_date
], [reg_numb], [idcead], [efile]) VALUES (100003, 7, 0, N'test', N'rtf', 4, N'test', '2012-05-11 21:05:12
.125', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0x61737373)←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mEXECUTE (0.0ms)←[0m  COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This config setting is for parameter logging - when you hit your controller with a params hash, these will be omitted from that hash in the log. In production mode, your SQL queries are not logged.

Comment: There is not a solution for development mode to disable particular fields logging. Am I right?